# Trusted certificate problem after restart of Windows

Tags: windows, iis, ssl, certificate

I'm currently developping a website with Visual Studio 2010 and IIS Express 7.5 on Windows 7 x64 in a VirtualBox VM.

I have followed this article and made it works like a charm.
[Working with SSL at Development Time is easier with IISExpress](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx)

The problem comes when I shut down my machine and start it back the next day. It doesn't work anymore, I have to redo the whole opertations in order to make it work.

Does anyone has an idea why everything is screwed up each time I restart my machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the exact same problem and have spent far too much time trying to figure out what the problem is. It was working ok before I rebooted :(

Answer (score 2):

I've had this exact problem with full blown IIS 7.5 and Server 2008.

My particular problem came about when moving the server authentication certificate (and associated private key) around (through dragging) in the MMC Certificate Manager.

There's a step in the tutorial you linked to where they ask you to "drag" the certificate from Personal to Trusted Root Certificates.  I'd suggest deleting that certificate from the Certificate Manager and importing it directly into the Trusted Root Certificates.

Comment: I realise that the problem is not linked to the certificate but to IIS Express and the firewall. After a restart the IIS Express works well with http://localhost:1040, http://dev-pc:80, https://localhost:44300 but it doesn't work anymore with https://dev-pc:443...

Comment: HTTPS ports are 44300 & 443. IIS answers to requests on 44300 but not on 443.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Code-signing private certificate, after reboot it was gone.
I found this on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/665140/certificate-stops-working-after-computer-reboot):

1. Right-click the certificate in MMC console ->All Tasks-> Manage Private Keys.
2. Add the needed users to access Now, Reboot the system and try it will work.
   enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the app.config as an administrator.

The other thing is you VM's hard drive might be writing changes to a read only delta which get's dropped when you restart, hence nothing is saved

Answer (score 0):

Thias was the solution for me:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/03/25/case-study-ssl-does-not-work-in-iis-7-5-after-server-reboots.aspx

Delete the certificate from the computer store and import it again. Dont drag and drop it from the user store.